# Question about cookies.permanent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I can not understand why:

```
cookies.permanent[:aaa] = 'bbb'
```

Create cookie with key = 'aaa' and value = 'bbb' but Expires period = 'Session' ???

I wanna have 20 years.

Help me, please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be something on the client end.

You can try

```
cookies[:aaa] = { :value => "bbb", :expires => 20.years.from_now }
```

And see if it does anything different.

On the other hand, this may be the wrong approach. Cookies are not guaranteed to last, because the user can change/delete them at any time. Worse, if the user fires up a different browser or uses a different machine, the cookie will not exist.

Maybe you can add whatever value you want to save to the user's record and then reference it every time she logs into your system.

Comment: Are you testing on a plain vanilla browser, with no add-ons/extensions/scripts/etc?

Comment: i try few browsers Google Chrome, Mozilla

Comment: maybe, i have problems with my rails?